# .NET WPF application UI structure

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm fairly new to WPF and .NET in general. What I am trying to do is to create an application that has multiple forms. My question is that how should navigate through these forms?

Imagine there are 10 forms and each form has a button on it saying "Next" and upon click, goes to the next form, except the last form which terminates the entire application, like an installer if you will.

What should the "Next" buttons do? Should they create a new object of the next form and close the current form? I noticed this has a closing/opening visual effect which made me realize maybe I'm not doing it right.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a Wizard like approach.. look at this thread 
[Developing wizard UI - WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144332/developing-wizard-ui-wpf)